# Can you rename a PrimaryKeyRelatedField in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to know if you can:

*Can you rename a PrimaryKeyRelatedField in django-rest-framework?*

Basically something like this:

```
class TicketBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    cc = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        new_name="my_new_name",
        queryset=Person.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        required=False
        )

   # ... other code
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for source? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm good call. That worked. thanks

Comment: Ah perfect. Guess I should add that as an answer then. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [source attribute](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) for the serializer field. So in this example, you would do:

```
class TicketBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_new_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source="cc",
        queryset=Person.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        required=False
        )

   # ... other code
```